# How can you rank certain total values with JavaScript within a form built in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple form in HTML. There are 3 sections (Section A, B and C). As the user fills out the form each section is calculated by displaying total points and percentage. I would like to rank the scores and display it in the ranking column but cannot seem to figure how to do it. For example if Section A has 4 points and Section B has 3 points and Section C has 0 points then section A would have the rank of 1, section B would have the rank of 2 and section C would have the rank of 3. Also having the ranking change as the form is being filled out would be ideal.

I am new to JavaScript and am having trouble on how to logically implement this. This is just a sample of my form. I really have a much larger form with more sections and questions. Please run my code so you can see a better visual. Any code snippets and advice that would help me will be appreciated. Also if you can keep my code as it is because I have alot more code depending on how my code is structured. I understand my code is not the best.

I've tried using if statements in JavaScript but like I said I can't wrap my mind around how to logically do it.

```js
function calcA1R() {
  var Aa1 = document.getElementById('Aa1');
  var Ab1 = document.getElementById('Ab1');
  var Ac1 = document.getElementById('Ac1');

  var Aa1Val = Aa1.options[Aa1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ab1Val = Ab1.options[Ab1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ac1Val = Ac1.options[Ac1.selectedIndex].value;

  // returning the sum of the values
  return [parseInt(Aa1Val), parseInt(Ab1Val), parseInt(Ac1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
}

function calcA1() {
  displaySumA()
}

function displaySumA() {
  document.getElementById('totalA').textContent = calcSumA()
  document.getElementById('TotalASummary').textContent = calcSumA()
  document.getElementById('TotalAPercent').textContent = Math.ceil(calcSumA() / 4 * 100) + '%'
}

function calcSumA() {
  return calcA1R()
}

function calcB1R() {
  var Ba1 = document.getElementById('Ba1');
  var Bb1 = document.getElementById('Bb1');
  var Bc1 = document.getElementById('Bc1');

  var Ba1Val = Ba1.options[Ba1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Bb1Val = Bb1.options[Bb1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Bc1Val = Bc1.options[Bc1.selectedIndex].value;

  // returning the sum of the values
  return [parseInt(Ba1Val), parseInt(Bb1Val), parseInt(Bc1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
}

function calcB1() {
  displaySumB()
}

function displaySumB() {
  document.getElementById('totalB').textContent = calcSumB()
  document.getElementById('TotalBSummary').textContent = calcSumB()
  document.getElementById('TotalBPercent').textContent = Math.ceil(calcSumB() / 4 * 100) + '%'
}

function calcSumB() {
  return calcB1R()
}

function calcC1R() {
  var Ba1 = document.getElementById('Ca1');
  var Bb1 = document.getElementById('Cb1');
  var Bc1 = document.getElementById('Cc1');

  var Ca1Val = Ca1.options[Ca1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Cb1Val = Cb1.options[Cb1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Cc1Val = Cc1.options[Cc1.selectedIndex].value;

  // returning the sum of the values
  return [parseInt(Ca1Val), parseInt(Cb1Val), parseInt(Cc1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
}

function calcC1() {
  displaySumC()
}

function displaySumC() {
  document.getElementById('totalC').textContent = calcSumC()
  document.getElementById('TotalCSummary').textContent = calcSumC()
  document.getElementById('TotalCPercent').textContent = Math.ceil(calcSumC() / 4 * 100) + '%'
}

function calcSumC() {
  return calcC1R()
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Category |</th>
    <th>Points Possible |</th>
    <th>Points Awarded |</th>
    <th>Percent Achieved |</th>
    <th>Ranking</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">A</td>
    <td align="center">4</td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalASummary"></span></div></b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalAPercent"></span></div></b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">B</td>
    <td align="center">4</td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalBSummary"></span></div></td>
           <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalBPercent"></span></div></td>
           <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="center">C</td>
           <td align="center">4</td>
           <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalCSummary"></span></div></td>
           <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalCPercent"></span></div></td>
           <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center"></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Section A.</th>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>A.1</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Aa1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ab1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c)</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ac1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Section A. Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>4</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalA"></span></div></b></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Section B.</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>B.1</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Ba1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Bb1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c)</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Bc1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Section B. Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>4</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalB"></span></div></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Section C.</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>C.1</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcC1();" id="Ca1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b)</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcC1();" id="Cb1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c)</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcC1();" id="Cc1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Section C. Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>4</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalC"></span></div></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you having trouble writing the ranking algorithm or something else? I can see you can update HTML when user input changes so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you just want to place a number in these three sections' "Rank" column based on how well the user performed in each?

You should be able to just compare the text content of the "Percent Achieved" columns (I assume that's what you want to compare).

Here's what I would do (after giving the top table an ID of 'results'):

```
function calculateRankings() {
  // grab all the spans that hold the percentages
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll('#results td:nth-child(4) span');

  // make a list of objects, making up a percentage and its corresponding rank column 
  const percentages = [];
  for (const span of spans) {
     percentages.push({
       //some way to select the neighboring rankings column:
       e: span.parentElement.nextSibling, // <<---- YOU'LL HAVE TO CHANGE THIS!!
       p: Number(span.innerText.replace('%', ''))
     });
  }

  // sort based on the percentage field of each object 
  percentages.sort((a, b) => a.p - b.p);

  // place an index based on the order of the list 
  for (let i = 0; i < percentages.length; i++) {
    percentages[i].e.innerText = i + 1;
  }
}
```

I didn't test this but it should be a good place to start.